# Preloading data from network in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, preload

I have a page that support pagination when loading data from network.

I'm using a UITableview to display list.

I want to preload next page when user scroll near the end of current page.

For example, each page has 10 items. When item 8 is visible in the screen, I shall start loading of next page immediately.

Which delegate method of UITableView is the best choice for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following method, It will get to know the display cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
//      Webservice Call for next 10 display data
    }
```

Discussion
A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can use it delegate methods. I suggest you to use this two:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    if (!decelerate) {
         NSSet *visibleRows = [NSSet setWithArray:[self.view.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];

    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSSet *visibleRows = [NSSet setWithArray:[self.view.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];

}
```

Check your clause after you get `visibleRows` and preload your data if, for example, last `indexPath.row` in NSSet is equal to your datasource array count (or is equal to [array count] - some_number_you_want )

To archive, when tableView start scrolling, you can implement your preload logic here:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSSet *visibleRows = [NSSet setWithArray:[self.view.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]];
// your update code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did some experiment and found out that use these dragging methods were not good enough in my situation. Then drag delegation happens too early and cannot get the final location.

Answer (score 0):

add this method in the `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{   
    CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - yOffset;

    if(distanceFromBottom < height) 
    {
        NSLog(@"end of the table and call web service or load more data");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried, but this method is called multiple time with one scroll gesture

Answer (score 0):

Use [UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) or [UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching) to preload data from network and have your cells ready when displayed to the user